# Does the 13-inch mid-2013 Macbook Air have a noisier keyboard than previous models?

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro

I just got a Apple-refurbished mid-2013 13-inch Macbook Air. It's great -- except that the keyboard is noticeably noisier than my previous model from mid-2011.

Specifically, they make more of a clicky sound, not when pressed, but just when you brush your fingers across them.

It seems they are looser and make a sound when the keys move laterally within their slots and touch the metal.

Is this by design for this model?

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone. I have the same model and the keyboard is also noisy. Although I get it with both typing and just brushing over the keys. I believe this is by design because a lot of people like having that tactile feel of a mechanical keyboard. While they can't get that built into such a thin computer this is their way of replicating it. Hope this helps!